# Hide/show Action Bar in Android activity

Tags: android, android-actionbaractivity

I have an android activity extended from ActionBarActivity.

My Activity content ruled by state pattern. When state changes, screen also changes somehow. I need ActionBar just in one of 3 states I have. How can I hide ActionBar by default and show it only in one State of my Activity?.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For hiding use

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

and for Showing it again use

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Comment: that is not what he is asking.. see *hide ActionBar by default*

Comment: the Activity which is calling this method should extends `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 1):

look at this example its work for me by default i hide my action bar layout after that i am showing it on user data requirements

[How to hide and show action bar](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-hide-and-show-action-bar/)